# Invalid Policy Document : AWS S3 CORS Upload Error

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Following [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) and getting this error. Using python to sign the policy doc

`InvalidPolicyDocument`Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON.xxxxxxxxCD2EI80iQvdVKMvl8mrMKDG62Obva4jddKQhNGDPCstjDd

This is my doc:

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "somebucket"},
        [
            "starts-with",
            "$key",
            "uploads/"
        ],
        {"acl": "private"},
        {"success_action_redirect": "http://www.foo.com/"},
        [
            "starts-with",
            "$Content-Type",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "content-length-range",
            0,
            1048576
        ]
    ],
    "expiration": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I know that it's a valid JSON!

Comment: Valid JSON, okay, but what's all of that base-64-looking "line noise" in the error message?  Does that suggest the think you think you're sending isn't the actual thing you're sending?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have not tested this, but it's possible that the policy parser is rejecting the empty string. I suspect this because it also rejects decimal numbers with the same "Invalid JSON" message.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a valid json, but doesn't look like a valid policy doc. What guide did you follow building it? Your link seems to be broken/unattached.

As far as I remember:

- `conditions` list not a valid item in policy, use `statement` list instead
- conditions for a given statement are represedted as `key: value` elements of `condition` dictionary

Look for samples [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html) and [there](http://s3browser.com/working-with-amazon-s3-bucket-policies.php). Also, you might find handy Amazon [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html).

Comment: @jarhead483 is asking about post policies: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html